# Modify data beafore binding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new at Xamarin Forms. I am binding data to ListView from my Web Server data base. I have 2 table in my web server.

1. Tb_Country
2. Tb_Region

There is a column country_id in the Tb_Region table. I am displaying region list in my ListView. But I am getting only country_id. I want to display also country title from Tb_Country.
How can I do that?

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  In order for us to help you we have to know what you are doing, and you haven not posted any relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a DataTemplate in the ListView?

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding)